# ffmpeg: How to generate alpha channel MOV from mp4 matte/webm

Tags: ffmpeg, video, video-conversion

I have two mp4 files, one file is alpha channel(matte key) and the other is original video, I convert them to .webm like

```
ffmpeg',
  '-i',
  './files/video.mp4',
  '-i',
 './files/video_matte_key.mp4',
  '-filter_complex',
  '[0][1]alphamerge,format=yuva420p',
  '-c:v',
  'libvpx',
  '-strict',
  '-2',
  '-auto-alt-ref',
  '0'
```

Everything is fine, but webm isn't supported on iOS devices, so I need to use .mov, any ideas how to convert same (mp4) files, or webm file to .mov file with alpha channel?

Good example of working .mov file (uses HEVC):
https://rotato.netlify.app/alpha-demo/movie-hevc.mov

Comment: Check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61661140/convert-webm-to-hevc-with-alpha) in the subject of HEVC with alpha. You may also look for other codecs as described [here](https://quick-adviser.com/can-mov-have-alpha-channel/).